# Using Firebase and SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I am very new to both firebase and Xcode SwiftUI. I found many tutorial on the storyboard but could not find tutorials for SwiftUI. I downloaded firebase using pod and the instruction given to us by the firebase documents. I created an AppDelegate.swift and copied the following code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      return true
    }
}
```

In the Firebase database, I created a user collection with an example value to test if it works.

So by using this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0#swift_3, I looked at the read data section and wrote the code in the ContentView.swift:

```
        db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
             }
        }
      }
```

But It says that it has to be a view.

How can I get the data in the firebase database into my Swiftui app?

Comment: You should start with the [Apple SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/) and you should look at the questions already in SO that concern [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SwiftUI+firebase+database). SwiftUI is a UI framework, your database code belongs in a 'class' where your you make an array of objects that can be used to fill in UI elements.

Comment: If you're looking for SwiftUI & Firebase tutorials, check out peterfriese.dev - I've got a bunch of tutorials covering exactly this topic.

Comment: And https://medium.com/firebase-developers/ios/home

Comment: Peter's tutorials are great! you can also go to tutshub.io for user-submitted resources.